# JavaScript - Problem splitting a long code line

Tags: javascript

I want to split this line because its too long.

```
ticketText = `*Environment:*\n${values["environment"]}\n\n*Observed on:*\n${values["observedOn"]}\n\n*Description:*\n${values["description"]}\n\n*Steps:*\n${steps}\n\n*Attachments:*`
```

I tried this but its adding space at the beginning of Observed on and Steps.

```
ticketText = `*Environment:*\n${values["environment"]}\n\n
*Observed on:*\n${values["observedOn"]}\n\n*Description:*\n${values["description"]}\n\n
*Steps:*\n${steps}\n\n*Attachments:*`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with this approach:

```js
const values = {
  environment: "UAT",
  observedOn: "Something",
  description: "Something"
};
const steps = "Something";
const ticketText =
  `*Environment:*\n${values["environment"]}\n\n` +
  `*Observed on:*\n${values["observedOn"]}\n\n` +
  `*Description:*\n${values["description"]}\n\n` +
  `*Steps:*\n${steps}\n\n*Attachments:*`;

console.log(ticketText);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [line continuation (\)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-template-literal-lexical-components)

```js
const values = { "observedOn":"Friday", "description":"Bla", "environment":"cold" }
const steps = 4;
ticketText = `*Environment:*\n${values["environment"]}\n\n\
*Observed on:*\n${values["observedOn"]}\n\n*Description:*\n${values["description"]}\n\n\
*Steps:*\n${steps}\n\n*Attachments:*`

console.log(ticketText)
```

Using clipboard

```js
const values = {
  "observedOn": "Friday",
  "description": "Bla",
  "environment": "cold"
};
const steps = 4;
const ticketText = `*Environment:*\n${values["environment"]}\n\n\
*Observed on:*\n${values["observedOn"]}\n\n*Description:*\n${values["description"]}\n\n\
*Steps:*\n${steps}\n\n*Attachments:*`
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(ticketText).then(function() {
    console.log('Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!');
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then(function(data) {
      document.getElementById("ta").value = data;
    });
  }, function(err) {
    console.error('Async: Could not copy text: ', err);
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">Paste from Clipboard</button><br/>
<textarea id="ta" rows=15 cols=50></textarea>
```

Comment: I tried that before but doesnt work good, its adding a space before Observed on and Steps. I have a button that copy that text to the clipboard and when I paste it I see those whitespaces

Comment: n o t   w o r k i n g

Comment: @Fran W o r k s  f o r  m e - see update - you need to allow clipboard access

Answer (score 0):

You can add `\` character to the end of each line:

```js
var values = {
  environment: 'environment',
  observedOn: 'observedOn',
  description: 'description'
};

var steps = 'steps';


console.log(`*Environment:*\n${values["environment"]}\n\n\
*Observed on:*\n${values["observedOn"]}\n\n*Description:*\n${values["description"]}\n\n\
*Steps:*\n${steps}\n\n*Attachments:*`)
```